# Why does my appium server skip my second emulator on parallel test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, appium, parallel-execution

I have done the following:

1. Start Selenium Grid
2. Started 2 emulator; Started appium servers for both using appium -p  --nodeconfig /absolute/path/.json
3. Ran my script:

   DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

   ```
        cap.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
        cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");

        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");//Nexus 5X API 24
        cap.SetCapability("devicePort", "5554");
        AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://localhost:<port>/wd/hub"), cap);



        var navigation = driver.Navigate();
        navigation.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        DesiredCapabilities cap2 = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap2.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
        cap2.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");

        cap2.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5556");//Nexus 5X API 24
        cap2.SetCapability("devicePort", "5556");
        AndroidDriver<IWebElement> driver2 = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://<myIP>:<appiumPort2>/wd/hub"), cap2);
        var navigation2 = driver2.Navigate();
        navigation2.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
   ```

Then on my nodeconfig it has the following:

```
   {
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "Chrome",
          "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
          "devicePort": "5554",
          "maxInstances": 2,
          "platform": "Android",
          "version": "8.0"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":300000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://10.42.43.59:4723/wd/hub",
    "host": "10.42.43.59",
    "port": 4723,
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "10.42.43.59"
  }
}
```

What it does is it only runs on one emulator even if I started both emulators and connected my ports to the respective emulator. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Can you attach the appium servers logs , I suspect you will see the answer there.

Comment: I have resolved this and looking at the logs, there is a conflicting port number for bootstrap and the appium server.